# Clamping Voltage without disturbing the power supply

Tags: microcontroller, pic, voltage-regulator

I am using a circuit similar to the following, to clamp the input to my microcontroller to around 5 volts:

[image]

How do I make sure that the (5V) power supply is not disturbed and stays regulated.

I am using linear regulator to maintain 5V from 12 volts supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current flowing into your +5V supply is limited by R5. The exact value depends on just how high Vin can go, but even 100V is only going to drive about 10 mA into the supply.

There are two ways to deal with this: either have a regulator that can sink any excessive current (rare), or make sure that the minimum load on the +5V bus is greater than 10 mA. If the existing circuit doesn't always draw at least this amount of current, you can add a resistor as a dummy load — 470 Ω would draw about 10 mA @ 5V.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Zenner like below. In this case you will not be using supply voltage. But it depends on the speed of the input signal as well. However,the falling edge will be dependent on R1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbxyvO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the purpose of D2?

Comment: It depends on application. You can remove D2 in some cases. It might be useful particularly if you use 5.1V/5.6V zenner, the clamping voltage might go little above 5V depending on R2 and Vin. So if you use D2, it will drop 0.6/0.7V and it ensures proper input for 5V circuit. If proper R2 and zenner are selected D2 can be removed.